# Are elements returned by lxml xpath function returned in order?

Tags: xpath, lxml

If I have a document such as the following:

```
<root>
    <child id="child-1"/>
    <child id="child-2"/>
    <child id="child-3"/>
</root>
```

And I have a xpath query such as the following:

```
//child[starts-with(@id, "child-")]
```

Is it guaranteed that the order in which I will get the results is same as that
in the document.

I have checked it for a few sample cases and it seems that elements are returned
in order. I am using lxml (version 3.2.3 and python 2.7).

More generally, if an xpath query matches a certain set of elements in
a document, are implementations required to return the elements in the order in
which they occur in the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Results will be generated as per the [**`Document order`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-document-order).

Comment: Could you provide a source for this? I tried to find this in the lxml documentation but had no luck.